# Agregar lista a ComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt5

Cuando intento agregar lstSeccion al ComboBox, tengo el siguiente error.

> Error: addItem(self, str, userData: Any = None): argument 1 has
>   unexpected type 'list' addItem(self, QIcon, str, userData: Any =
>   None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'

Codigo:

```
self.dlg.comboBox.addItem(lstSeccion)
```

Datos de lstSeccion:

```
['Situacion', 'Contexto', 'Detalle', 'Observacion']
```

Comment: El método `addItem` como su nombre  y firma indica acepta una cadena como primer argumento y añade un solo item por tanto. Lo que necesitas usar es el método [`addItems`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#addItems)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones. O bien haces `addItems` como te ha sugerido @FJSevilla, o puedes usar un loop (aunque no es lo más adecuado, salvo que quieras conseguir la información de diccionarios, registros de bases de datos o lugares más complicados).

sin loop:

```
lstSeccion = ['Situacion', 'Contexto', 'Detalle', 'Observacion']
self.dlg.comboBox.addItems(lstSeccion)
```

con loop:

```
lstSeccion = ['Situacion', 'Contexto', 'Detalle', 'Observacion']
for i in lstSeccion:
    self.dlg.comboBox.addItem(i)
```